# ul being pushed out of div

Tags: html, css

I'm currently experiencing an issue where my ul is being pushed out of my div. I have played with the margin, border, and padding on all the objects that might be affecting it with no success as of yet, here is the current code:

HTML:

```
            <div id="nav">
                <ul id=mainNav>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>Products</a></li>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>Stores</a></li>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>About Us</a></li>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class=mainNav><a>Pet Pics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="subBar">

            <div id="subNav">
            <ul id=subNavl>
                    <li class=subNav><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li class=subNav><a>Products</a></li>
                    <li class=subNav><a>Stores</a></li>
                    <li class=subNav><a>About Us</a></li>
                    <li class=subNav><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class=subNav><a>Pet Pics</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#B443B7;
    border-radius:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:opx;
    }


h1{
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    }

h1, a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#B443B7;  
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    }



    #subBar {
        height:20px;
        padding-top:10px;
        width:875px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        background-color:#F4F459;
        color:black;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;

        }

#nav {
    margin:auto;
    }

#subNav {
    margin:auto;    
}

#mainNav {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.mainNav {
    display:inline

}

.mainNav a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    padding-top:15px;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

.mainNav a:hover{
    background-color:#F4F459;
    color:black;
}

#subNavl {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.subNav {
    display:inline

}

.subNav a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    color:black;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

And here's a screen shot of the results:

[image]

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: My guess is it's because you are changing the `display` to be variations on `inline` . A `ul` is naturally a block-level element, and should probably stay that way unless you know what you're doing with `display`

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle.net? I've also noticed that there is a closing div tag on line 13 of your html that doesn't have an opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/gorabonoqe/1/

I dropped your code in a JSBin and didn't look exactly like your screenshot but I think I was able to address the area you were trying to fix (the text dropping out of the yellow bar).

There's a lot of potential issues going on here. For one, all `<a>` elements have a bottom margin of 60px. I think that's what was throwing you off the most. I also changed the padding on `#subBar` and added a margin:0 on `#subNavl`.

Take a look at the jsbin link above and see if that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks I copied in your version of the CSS and it seems to be working correctly, I'm still trying to rap my head around what exactly was causing though.

Comment: Looking at it again, I think another thing throwing you off was that the `#subNavl` element is a `<ul>`, which by default has a top-margin on it. (Browsers all provide default styling on HTML elements). That was also causing that sub nav to drop down. While my answer may have directly fixed your code, @Mohamed-Yousef's answer is correct as well and illustrates a best practice when it comes to styling navs. If you're looking to learn more about CSS, this site is a good  resource http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know .. when you work with ul > li > a

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul > li{
   display : inline-block; 
}
ul > li > a{
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
}
```

this way will make everything comes easy in your ul code

Answer (score 0):

You set the height of that div, #subBar, to 20px and the browser is obeying that.